# Passing object Bundle intent in Serializable class

Tags: java, android, serialization, android-intent, bundle

I must mention i am new to Android and Java. I am trying this for a weeek to solve. 
I have Serializable class wich object are populated with http json, and i am using adapters to populate listviews and everything works fine but when i want to pass to another class one object i it force closes, please if somebody can correct my code.

this void is in Serializable class

```
  public void save(){
 Intent intent =  new Intent();
 Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
  intent.putExtra("title", getTitle()); 

           }
```

when i try this:

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(this, Fragment2.class);  i got error The constructor   
Intent(FeedItem, Class<Fragment2>) is undefined
```

and this is fragment class where i want to use passed object

```
     Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
 Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
 FeedItem feedItem = (FeedItem)getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("title");
 String title = feedItem.getTitle();
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

error The value of the local variable extras is not used

Many thanks.

Comment: Are `FeedItem` and `Fragment2` both extending `Activity`?

Comment: getTitle() is returning String or FeedItem object?

Comment: Fragment2 extends Fragment and FeedItem implements Serializable

Comment: Title is an object, and i am using it getTitle to put it in Intent

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are added like this

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(resourceidwhereyouwantadd(R.id.view), new YourFragment());
            ft.commit();
```